# cannot modify drop down boxes in lynx

Tags: lynx

I'm using lynx version 2.8.7rel1 on cygwin.  When I try to change a drop down box, I get the following message when it is highlighted: "UNMODIFIABLE option list", and I cannot change its value from the default.  How can this problem be fixed?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug in lynx 2.8.7-1

It looks similar to this bug which was reported fixed in 2005:

> fix:  when first "option" element of "select" had "disabled" attribute, Lynx
>     turned the entire "option/choice list" UNMODIFIABLE.  The "disabled"
>     attribute of later "option" elements within the same "select" did not have
>     this effect.  If the "disabled" attribute is honored, it should disable only
>     that element, not parent element or sibling elements (report by Paavo
>     Hartikainen) -TD

You can work around this problem by reverting to lynx 2.8.5-4 instead of 2.8.7-1 (2.8.5-4 is still available in cygwin -- when you are in the "Select Packages" interface, click on the version number for lynx in the "New" column until that version appears).